# tikzpicture tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
\node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$C(0, 1)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(0, 1)$};
\node (b1) at ( 4,1.5) [bag] {$C(\Delta t, 1)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (b2) at ( 4,-1.5) [bag] {$C(\Delta t, 2)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c1) at ( 8,3) [bag] {$C(2\Delta t, 1)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(2\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (c2) at ( 8,0) [bag] {$C(2\Delta t, 2)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(2\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c3) at ( 8,-3) [bag] {$C(2\Delta t, 3)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(2\Delta t, 3)$};
\draw [->] (a) to node [above]{} (b1);
\draw [->] (a) to node [below]{} (b2);
\draw [->] (b1) to node [above]{} (c1);
\draw [->] (b1) to node [above]{} (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) to node [above]{} (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) to node [above]{} (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}
$$

$$
 \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
   \node (a) at ( 0,0) [bag] {$j\Delta S$};
   \node (b1) at ( 3,2) [bag] {$(j-1)\Delta S$};
   \node (b2) at ( 3,0) [bag]  {$j\Delta S$};
   \node (b3) at ( 3,-2) [bag] {$(j+1)\Delta S$};   
   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$p$} (b1);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$1-p-q$} (b2);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [below] {$q$} (b3);

\end{tikzpicture}
$$

\end{document}
```

The pictures are shown below.
There are three problems:

1. In the first picture, arrows overlap the formula in the middle.
2. To spread the first line and second line in the formula, I use very naive way
   `$C(\Delta t, 2)$\\\vspace{5pt}$S(\Delta t, 2)$,` is there any effective way?
3. In the second picture, why the formula `$(j-1)\Delta S$` automatically change the line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include the definition of the `bag` style. And unrelated comment: [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Presumably your `bag` style includes a `text width` setting that is too narrow, so that the longer nodes in the second diagram are broken across two lines.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. How to define a suitable `bag`style here?

Comment: Empty would probably be suitable. But regardless of that, please edit your question to include the definition you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Both your first and last problem has the same cause: the definition of `bag`. You haven't shown us the exact definition, but I'm guessing you have something like

```
bag/.style={text width=0.5cm}
```

Setting `text width` means that the `node` becomes a `minipage` like box with the given width. That in turn means that LaTeX will automatically add line breaks if the node text becomes longer, but if no break points are found, you'll end up with an overfull box, i.e. the text will protrude out of the box on the right side. However, the size of the node will not be influenced by such an overflow.

You can see how this causes your problem 1 and 3 if you add `draw` to the `bag` style, in which case you get this:

[image: bag,draw]

(You may also have noticed that you get a lot of *overfull hbox* warnings from this.)

### Possible solution

#### Point 1 and 3

```
bag/.style={align=left}
```

Setting `align` will allow for line breaks (`\\`), but the width of the node will be the length of the longest line.

#### Point 2

- `\\` takes an optional argument to specify additional distance, so you could do `\\[5pt]` instead of the more verbose `\vspace`.
- Another option would be to add `\usepackage{setspace}` to the preamble, and define the `bag` style as

  ```
   bag/.style={align=left,font=\onehalfspacing}
  ```

  (or `\doublespacing`, if `\onehalfspacing` isn't enough).
- A third option would be to first define a new macro:

  ```
  \newcommand\minimathtab[1]{%
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}% % modify 1.4 to suit your need
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{}}
    #1
    \end{tabular}
  }
  ```

  In the diagram, don't use the `bag` style (or in fact any style), but apply that macro:

  ```
  \node (a)  {\minimathtab{C(0, 1) \\ S(0, 1)}};
  ```

### Other things to note

- Don't use `$$ .. $$` in LaTeX. For unnumbered displayed equations, use `\[ ... \]`. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

  In this case though, I would probably just use a `center` environment.
- You've loaded the `positioning` library, but you're not using its features. It allows for positioning nodes relative to other nodes, at a distance that can be set for the entire diagram. This means you can position everything without using explicit coordinates, and it's very easy to adjust the spacing, as you only need to adjust the `node distance`

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{bag/.style={align=left,font=\onehalfspacing}}

\newcommand\minimathtab[1]{%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{}}
   #1
   \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % first value is vertical separation, second value is horizontal 
  node distance=2mm and 1.5cm
]

\begin{scope}[
  % apply the bag style to all the nodes inside the scope environment
  every node/.style=bag
]
\node                     (a)  {$C(0, 1) $ \\ $ S(0, 1)$};
\node [above right=of a]  (b1) {$C(\Delta t, 1) $ \\ $ S(\Delta t, 1)$};
\node [below right=of a]  (b2) {$C(\Delta t, 2) $ \\ $ S(\Delta t, 2)$};
\node [above right=of b1] (c1) {$C(2\Delta t, 1) $ \\ $ S(2\Delta t, 1)$};
\node [below right=of b1] (c2) {$C(2\Delta t, 2) $ \\ $ S(2\Delta t, 2)$};
\node [below right=of b2] (c3) {$C(2\Delta t, 3) $ \\ $ S(2\Delta t, 3)$};
\end{scope}

\draw [->] (a) -- (b1);
\draw [->] (a) -- (b2);
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c1);
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,node distance=1cm and 2cm]
   \node (a) {$j\Delta S$};
   \node [above right=of a] (b1) {$(j-1)\Delta S$};
   \node [right=of a] (b2)  {$j\Delta S$};
   \node [below right=of a] (b3) {$(j+1)\Delta S$};   

   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$p$}     (b1.south west);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$1-p-q$} (b2);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [below] {$q$}     (b3.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm and 1.5cm]
\node                     (a)  {\minimathtab{C(0, 1) \\ S(0, 1)}};
\node [above right=of a]  (b1) {\minimathtab{C(\Delta t, 1) \\ S(\Delta t, 1)}};
\node [below right=of a]  (b2) {\minimathtab{C(\Delta t, 2) \\ S(\Delta t, 2)}};
\node [above right=of b1] (c1) {\minimathtab{C(2\Delta t, 1) \\ S(2\Delta t, 1)}};
\node [below right=of b1] (c2) {\minimathtab{C(2\Delta t, 2) \\ S(2\Delta t, 2)}};
\node [below right=of b2] (c3) {\minimathtab{C(2\Delta t, 3) \\ S(2\Delta t, 3)}};


\draw [->] (a) -- (b1);
\draw [->] (a) -- (b2);
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c1);
\draw [->] (b1) -- (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c2);
\draw [->] (b2) -- (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I think the third other thing to note needs some clarification.

Comment: @cfr Hm, I think you might actually have a point there.

Answer (score 1):

see, it this is what you looking for:

- instead `$$ ... $$` i use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` for two reasons:

  1. `$$` belong to `tex` syntax and not to `latex`
  2. i don't see any benefits to has `tikzpicture` images in math environment
- i omit use of `bag` style. it seems that it is source of your problem, but its purpose is not clear. it is not used for automatic break nodes content into two lines,
- i remove manual adding vertical space between lines in nodes and replace it by following image style definition:

```
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped, 
align = left, 
 font = \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
                         ]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

- *mwe* below also contain simple solution with automatic break longer text into two lines
- second image can be also drawn as simple tree as can be seen in *mwe* below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped, 
align = left, 
 font = \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
                         ]
\node (a)               {$C(0,1)$\\         $S(0, 1)$};
\node (b1) at (4, 1.5)  {$C(\Delta t,1)$\\  $S(\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (b2) at (4,-1.5)  {$C(\Delta t,2)$\\  $S(\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c1) at (8, 3.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,1)$\\ $S(2\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (c2) at (8, 0.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,2)$\\ $S(2\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c3) at (8,-3.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,3)$\\ $S(2\Delta t, 3)$};
\draw [->]  (a)  edge (b1)
            (a)  edge (b2)
            (b1) edge (c1)
            (b1) edge (c2)
            (b2) edge (c2)
            (b2) edge (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

% first image with automatic breaking cells content into more lines
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,
     align = left,
      font = \linespread{1.2}\selectfont,
text width = 9ex 
                         ]
\node[align=right]  (a) {$C(0,1)$         $S(0, 1)$};
\node (b1) at (4, 1.5)  {$C(\Delta t,1)$  $S(\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (b2) at (4,-1.5)  {$C(\Delta t,2)$  $S(\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c1) at (8, 3.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,1)$ $S(2\Delta t, 1)$};
\node (c2) at (8, 0.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,2)$ $S(2\Delta t, 2)$};
\node (c3) at (8,-3.0)  {$C(2\Delta t,3)$ $S(2\Delta t, 3)$};
\draw [->]  (a)  edge (b1)
            (a)  edge (b2)
            (b1) edge (c1)
            (b1) edge (c2)
            (b2) edge (c2)
            (b2) edge (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,
    node distance=2cm and 3cm]
   \node (a)  at (0, 0) {$j\Delta S$};
   \node (b1) at (3, 2) {$(j-1)\Delta S$};
   \node (b2) at (3, 0) {$j\Delta S$};
   \node (b3) at (3,-2) {$(j+1)\Delta S$};
   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$p$} (b1.south west);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [above] {$1-p-q$} (b2.west);
   \draw [->] (a) to node [below] {$q$} (b3.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

% second image drawn as tree
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped,
    level distance=30mm,
    sibling distance=15mm,
    grow=right,
    edge from parent/.style = {draw, semithick, ->},
    edge from parent path=
{(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
                    ]
\node  {$j\Delta S$}
    child{node {$(j-1)\Delta S$}    edge from parent node[above] {$p$}}
    child{node {$j\Delta S$}        edge from parent node[above] {$1-p-q$}}
    child{node {$(j+1)\Delta S$}    edge from parent node[above] {$q$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]